# 'ninja' segments - do they exist?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

This question is about a sort of "weak topological $k$-mixing" where the
$k$-point set is replaced by a (topological) segment.

Let $f:M\rightarrow M$ be a homeomorphism on a (compact) topological manifold
$M$. I am looking for a system with the following property: There is a
topological segment $C\subset M$ such that for any connected set $A\subset M$
and any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $n$ so that
$d(f^{n}(C),A)<\varepsilon~$,
where $d$ is the Hausdorff distance (with respect to some fixed metric on
$M$). Such $C$ is a kind of a 'ninja' as it approximates any connected region
of $M$ with arbitrary precision.

The reason for this question is that for a class of systems I have an idea how
to construct a 'ninja set' $C$ with respect to all subsets of $M$, but this
$C$ is not connected, it is zero dimensional. So it is a natural question to
ask whether connected ninjas exist and the most simple connected set is the
segment. (Note that a connected ninja may approximate only connected sets.) I
don't believe that 'ninja segments' exist in dimension 2 as there is no enough
space for a ninja to operate.

In case the answer is affirmative, one may ask about smooth systems with this
property or to look for 'ninjas' in some known systems.

s::l

Comment: what is a topological segment?

Comment: @Nishant: I'd assume that "topological segment" means arc, i.e., homeomorphic copy of the interval $[0,1]$ --- unless and until someone tells me otherwise.